# How to convert a stringified object to object in Java?

Tags: java, string, object

I need to store objects in Java as strings and then transform them back to their object form. For example, a stringified Dog class looks like this: `Dog@d716361`.

Any idea how can I do that or another way to store objects as strings would be appreciated.

The class:

```
public class Dog {
    private String name;
    
    Dog(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a stringified version of the object, that's the reference of the instance.  If you need to store the objects as strings and then convert them back to objects you can use a ready-made library such as Jackson [`ObjectMapper`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) or similar.

Comment: Override [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) `toString() { return getName(); }`?

Comment: @blurfus That is not a reference of the instance, it is the default `toString()` implementation provided by `Object`, which prints the fully qualified class name followed by `@` and the hex encoding of the identity hashcode of the object (which could be a reference in theory, but in practice is not as Java moves objects around in memory, while the identity hashcode remains the same).

Comment: It was a simplified explanation for OP :)